# Tensorflow seems to be using two GPUs but one GPU seems not be doing anything

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, multi-gpu

I just build a system with two GTX 680 GPUs. To test my system I'm running [cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py), training CIFAR10 using Tensorflow.

Tensorflow creates two Tensorflow devices based on the GPUs (last two lines):

```
$ python tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
>> Downloading cifar-10-binary.tar.gz 100.0%
Successfully downloaded cifar-10-binary.tar.gz 170052171 bytes.
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 680
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.15
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.15GiB
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x28eb270
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 680
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.15
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.90GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 1 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 1:   Y Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 680, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 680, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
```

However, when monitoring the GPUs during training (using `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi`), I noticed that the second GPU isn't getting hot at all (71 degrees for GPU0 vs 30 degrees for GPU1):

```
Every 1,0s: nvidia-smi                                  Mon Apr 24 01:30:40 2017

Mon Apr 24 01:30:40 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.51                 Driver Version: 375.51                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 680     Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 43%   71C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   3947MiB /  4036MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 680     Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   30C    P8    N/A /  N/A |   3737MiB /  4036MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
|    1                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also note here that the memory of both GPUs are completely allocated.

**Why is my second GPU not used?**

Comment: I don't think the GPUs are being used at all, the memory might be too small to allocate anything on it. Add verbose logging to see if anything gets assigned to them.

Comment: @fabrizioM I'm almost sure the first GPU is used, the number of examples per second is not bad (~1250/sec), further the temperature of the first GPU goes down when I stop the Python script. Nothing happens with the second GPU. Will try adjusting the verbosity level.

Comment: @fabrizioM Setting tf.logging.set_verbosity(DEBUG) did not give me more output. Does this tell anything? 'creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x28eb270'

Comment: @fabrizioM I just figured out my issue, thanks for responding though!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I should have taken more time in reading the script:

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_gpus', 1,
                            """How many GPUs to use.""")
```

I just set this to two, and everything works just fine:

```
Every 1,0s: nvidia-smi                                  Mon Apr 24 02:44:30 2017

Mon Apr 24 02:44:30 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.51                 Driver Version: 375.51                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 680     Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 37%   63C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   3807MiB /  4036MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 680     Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 36%   61C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   3807MiB /  4036MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
|    1                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would have expected that the script would automatically use all the GPUs available.

Getting around 2450 examples/sec, 0.051 sec/batch with [cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py).